# Why can a variable be bound to another value even its ownership has moved?

Tags: rust

In the following code, the ownership of `MyStruct { s: 5u32 }` is moved to `y` by `let y = x;`, but why does `x.s = 6` still work?

```
struct MyStruct {
    s: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = MyStruct { s: 5u32 };
    let y = x;
    x.s = 6; //why this line does not cause an error?
    println!("{}", y.s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, since adding the line `println!("{}", x.s)` at the end causes the compiler to complain.